# How to parse Microsoft Dto Url into Android and display as ListView

Tags: android, windows, azure, jackson, dto

I am trying to use Jackson XML from Github and parse the following Microsoft DTO Url into a ListView within Android:

http://94d5d2ca8b8347c19478bfaaf058ac65.cloudapp.net/api/landingpage/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

To get:

Title

ImageUrl

Snippet

FeedSource -> name

Do I first parse in as XML, or can I force the response from request to be as JSON? Also tried reading Gson and looked at Windows Azure cloud (where this URL came from) but couldnt see any examples.

Comment: Gson can't be used to parse XML like you have, but it can only parse JSON...

Comment: Thanks @MikO so what about reading in XML response and do the conversion inside Android to JSON? Can Jackson or other libs that can do that efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

As I say in the comment, Gson can only parse JSON (not XML!), so it makes no sense to use it if you want to parse an XML file like the one you have... (in fact I'll retag your post). It makes even less sense to convert XML to JSON as you pointed out in your comment...

Since you have a XML file, what you need to do is to parse the XML data into Java classes, and in order to do that you need a XML Parser. In Android, they recommend to use the parser [**XmlPullParser**](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html). There is very complete documentation, including many step-by-step examples in [**Andoid Developers**](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html) site.

Note that although they recommend that parser from Android, you can use other XML parsers, for example you can just use the DOM parser, which is perhaps the most basic one and you don't need any external library, like in [**this example**](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/). In fact in this last example they precisely build a `ListView` from a XML file as you're trying to do...

Comment: Not sure if exactly true as this Dto link when read into iOS device, can be parsed as JSON?

Comment: I don't know about that... if you can get a JSON file instead a XML file and you prefer to use a JSON parser, include the link with the JSON response instead of the XML response, and we'll try to help...

Comment: It seems that that's another library (it's not Gson library, but it's used with Gson) to convert XML to JSON, which could be useful for example if you have a XML file and want to send the data in that XML in a JSON format or something like that... But in your case I think that convert your XML into JSON and then into Java classes means to add an unnecesary intermediate step... Unless you have some special requirement you've not commented, I suggest you to parse directly the XML using good XML parsers as I recommended...